# TypeError: Product.deleteMany is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my code to automatically feed data into my database. The connection is correct as if we comment out the `await Product.deleteMany()` but when the following code is compiled and run, we get the error **"TypeError: Product.deleteMany is not a function"**. Please help.
Code:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const connectDB = require('./db/connect')
const Product = require('./models/product')

const jsonProducts = require('./products.json')

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    await Product.deleteMany()
    await Product.create(jsonProducts)
    console.log('Success!!!!')
    process.exit(0)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

start()
```

ConnectDB code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = (url) => {
  return mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

Products model:

```
const mongoose =  require('mongoose')

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'products name must be provided']
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'products price must be provided']
    },
    featured: {
        type:Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: 4.5
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    company:{
        type: String,
        enum:{
            values: ['ikea', 'liddy', 'caressa', 'marcos'],
            message: '{VALUE}  is not supported'
        } 
                // enum: ['ikea', 'liddy', 'caressa', 'marcos']
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',productSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in rating section of Products model

```
rating: {
  type: Number,
  required: 4.5
}
```

The correct format will be,

```
rating: {
  type: Number,
  default: 4.5
}
```

Which makes it an invalid model and therefore no function exists for an invalid model.